# Getting segmentation fault while removing one element in it

Tags: c++, linked-list

This is a code that will remove one actor in a one cast. I make a connection between the movies and their cast. So this code is checking whether movie exists and then it looks its Cast and when it finds the actor that we're looking for it deletes it. 
HOWEVER, while this code seems so reasonable for me, I'm getting segmentation fault.
What can be the reason, what we should take care in this cases not to get a segfault?

Comment: Did you try to debug it? Where exactly it crashes?

Comment: I'll bet it all here: `c-> next->...`. Why don't you check whether `c->next != 0`

Comment: What's reasonable about this? Why not use a `std::list` like a sane person?!

Comment: Hahahhaa. I like torture. I want to understand the structure of pointers and nodes thats why i did like this :D

Answer (score 1):

At the point

```
if( c-> next ->  name == actorFirstName && c -> next -> lastName == actorLastName)
```

you are assuming c->next is not NULL yet your loop only ensures c is not NULL.

Comment: so you mean that i should change c!= NULL with c -> next != NULL ?

Comment: It isn't quite that easy.  You should probably keep a "last" pointer to track the last valid cast member and then use it in the delete action.  If there wasn't a previous valid cast member (last == NULL), then you need to change the list head pointer.  By doing that, you can then do your comparisons with "c" instead of "c->next".  As it is, your code would also fail to find the cast member if they are the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Like DrC said, the "next" is wrong. Try this:

```
    void MovieDatabase:: removeActor( const string movieTitle, const string actorFirstName, const string actorLastName )
{
        for(Movie* m= headMovie; m != NULL;  m = m-> next){
               if(m-> title == movieTitle && m -> headCast !=NULL){
                        for(Cast* c = m -> headCast; c != NULL; c= c-> next){
                                if( c ->  name == actorFirstName && c -> lastName == actorLastName){
                                        Cast* temp = c-> next;
                                        delete c;
                                        c = temp;


                           }
                    }
            }
    }

}
```